# CodeLite won't detect (installed) MinGW -- and will not compile even with manual configuration

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw, mingw-w64, codelite

I installed CodeLite and was rightfully put in the direction to install MinGW. I installed MinGW right from where CodeLite suggests/links to it and everything went well there. I then click "scan" on CodeLite to find the just installed compiler and it says it can't find any on the system -- lost already here.

I then just tried to configure the directory of the compiler to one which is provided with MinGW, such as gcc. I try to compile any basic hello world or such and get the error that, "The system cannot find the file path specified." When trying by default it would compile even before actually properly setting up the compiler, so it seems completely backwards on the face of it. Maybe it's some cross/directory issue?

The log shows CMD.exe looking to cd to some weird/incorrect directory. I've changed environment variables to only include MinGW's path and the issue persists. I've changed around global settings/include paths/build settings to point to the compiler, but it just won't get past this.

Aside from manual setup not working and CodeLite being unable to find MinGW despite it being 100% verified and installed properly, I am basically lost here.

I have prior programming experience, but usually with everything out of the box. I'm now trying to get back in but wanted to learn the process of setting up a compiler/getting more "hands on."

I'm pretty sure it's something set up wrong by me, but the problem is clearly that I have no idea what.

Comment: Any spaces in any of the installation directory names?

Answer (score 3):

CodeLite does not need the compiler to be in the path. You can "tell" CodeLite where it is installed by pointing it to the right folder from `Settings->Build Settings`

See [this wiki page](https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/AddNewCompiler), note that the build settings dialog is a bit outdated, the drop down button does not exist anymore, instead you have a toolbar with green `+` button, click it instead.

Once you added the compiler, right click on your project and and select `Project Settings`, under the `General` tab, choose the compiler you just configured.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue where I had MinGW installed and working, then I downloaded CodeLite and went into the setup wizard, where it could not find MinGW.

Essentially the fix I found was closing and re-opening CodeLite.

I saw on the CodeLite site that the compiler should not be in a folder path with spaces in it, so I moved my compiler from "Program Files" to "ProgramFiles" and manually pointed to it using Settings -> Build Settings. However, CodeLite's scan still couldn't find it until I restarted it.

Then I moved my compiler back to its original folder and restarted CodeLite again, it worked.